# Unable to GIT : Error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: gitlab

I can't pull code anymore. I tried to set path git but it still doesn't work..
i also switched off SSL checks

```
$ git pull origin develop-Avaya
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/Tuong_Nguyen1/OCMT.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
```

Comment: Can you please try to use this command. `git config --system http.sslverify false`

Comment: i tried it, but  i can't lock config b/c permission denied

Comment: Then you must have to check your permission. Try with the root user.

Comment: please show me how more clearly....i'm a newbie

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue due to the fact that my domain was migrated and hence the path of ca-bundle.crt file was no longer valid as it had changed from

C:/Users/**empid**/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt  to
C:/Users/**username**/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

If you know the path to your ca-bundle.crt file, then you can simply run this command in cmd to add the config file from the correct location i.e.

*git config --global http.sslCAInfo C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt*

Once you run the above (with relevant path) and you don't get any issues, you are done.

Just for verification, when you run this command :

*git config --list --show-origin*

this file (the one whose path you gave in 1st command) will come in the list of config files (probably, the last one in the list)

If it does, then you are good to go. You can run any git command now and you would most likely get the prompt to enter the username and password for the very first time.